# Show *year* on Ubuntu 20.04 top bar

Tags: clock

As far as I can tell, there are no tweaks for showing the year on the top bar clock in Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa). I find it for < 20.04, but I can't find a suitable solution for Ubuntu 20.04.

Our service frequently needs to take screenshots identifying the *year* of a screenshot and the Ubuntu clock only believes in hour minute seconds date and day of week.  That doesn't help people who need to record the *year* in a screenshot.

Comment: If you open a bug report with your (very valid) justification and share the link, I would be willing to mark myself as impacted by the bug.

Comment: Depending on what your service is, and why it is important to record the year, note that the existence of a method to do this demonstrates that the information could also be faked, so you may need to record a timestamp out-of-band.

Answer (score 16):

I needed the same thing, and nerd-sniped my friend Stuart Langridge to develop this functionality. He made a great GNOME Extension called [Clock Override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) which enables you to put whatever you want in the clock area in the centre of the screen.

You can configure it to say anything. The settings below will show a very verbose time such as "2021-03-06T23:23:00+00:00" but you can of course make it say something shorter.

[image: Clock Override configuration]

Comment: Surprised that gnome lost that setting, unity still has it.

Comment: ...and it's not like there is not enough space in that vast empty Gnome top bar!

Comment: I dimly remember that you have to be careful with displaying the year, as there is also a format string that displays the year that the current week belongs to.